# Php script to get addon domain directory name with main ftp cred. and url

Tags: php, ftp, dns, subdomain, php-5.3

I have make a script to connect FTP with PHP script and now I am currently trying to get path for each specific domain directory within multi-domain hosting in my cpanel.

For example ::
in my cpanel there's 3 different domain's directory created like
1. xyz.com --- > /public_html/xyz
2. abc.com ----> /public_heml/abc
3. wsx.com -----> /public_html/text

somtime there's name is same directory for correspond name but sometime it's differet as per assign dirctory for each domain.

MY question :::
I want to get path like "/public_html/text" for each correspond domain directory from multi-domain hosting.

I am using this code so far to connect FTP and others for get this output...

```
<?php
$ftppass = json_encode($_REQUEST['ftp_password']);
$ftpserver = json_encode($_REQUEST['ftp_server']);
$ftpuser = json_encode($_REQUEST['ftp_username']);
$ftpfolder = json_encode($_REQUEST['ftp_folder']);
$server =json_decode($ftpserver); 
$user =json_decode($ftpuser); 
$pass =json_decode($ftppass); 
$folder =json_decode($ftpfolder);
//die($pass);
$connect = ftp_connect($server); 
        $login   = ftp_login($connect, $user, $pass);

          if($ftpfolder!=""){
              ftp_mkdir($connect, $folder);
              } 
        // check connection
        if (!$connect || !$login) { 
        $test['1']='FTP connection has failed!';
            $test =json_encode($test);
            print_r($test); 
        } else {
            $test['0']="Connected to {$ftpServer}, for user {$ftpUser}";
            $test =json_encode($test);
            print_r($test); 

        }


ftp_close($connect);   
?>
```

Any Idea about this ??????

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be specific about your problem.  What have you tried so far?  What was the result?  What are you having difficulty getting correct?  Also give the exact output that you would want for the example sites you mentioned.

Comment: Actually I have tried to got root directory path of a domain to copy files with php script, in a multi-site hosting server. I have main ftp credential (which located outside the public_html folder) and domain name of  where I want to put my files through php script from other website.
@dg99 thanks for your reply.